# Problemas com encoding em página estática

Tags: html5, node.js, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Eu tenho um arquivo html enviado de um servidor Node.js que pode ser acessado [aqui](https://www.mandallacomunicacao.com.br/) que está com problemas com a acentuação.

Eles estava funcionando normalmente, porém, após uma pequena atualização, ele ficou com esse problema. Quando eu o abro com o localhost, funciona, mas pelo domínio, não. Alguém tem alguma solução?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Qual IDE você utilizou ao salvar o arquivo? (Notepad++, PHPDesigner, Brackets, Atom, etc)

Comment: Eu usei o atom.

Comment: Na hora de salvar, ele não salvou o arquivo na codificação UTF-8. Por isso a acentuação ficou incorreta. No notepad++ é assim: "Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/Default Directory to automatically convert ANSI files to UTF-8 without BOM on open", no ATOM fica embaixo https://cdn-business.discourse.org/uploads/github_atom/original/3X/a/e/ae6b226e5f378682dd456cd4d0b11c78b8bc907d.PNG

Comment: @Everson, obrigado pela luz que me destes. Na resposta eu explico rsrs.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido, a hospedagem conta com um editor online de arquivos e como era uma pequena atualização, eu o utilizei. Porém ele salvou o arquivo em algum outro encode que não utf-8. Dessa vez, salvei no atom e subi, e agora está tudo certo.

Comment: Como suspeitei hehe